# How can I combine many C++ main() functions into a single binary?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I'm working with a large C++ project that presently produces 66 different binaries. Each entrypoint contains its own global variables and `main()` function, though there's a lot of common code that's provided through a shared library.

For ease of distribution, I would like to distribute a single statically-linked binary, like you'd get from a Go or Rust project. Instead of invoking:

```
./ProgramFoo
./ProgramBar
```

I'd like to have a single combined binary that "execs" itself into one of those tools behind the scenes based on argv parameters, sort of like how busybox works:

```
./CombinedProgram ProgramFoo
./CombinedProgram ProgramBar
```

Look, I get that there's a "right" way to do this — refactor all 66 source files. Replace all global state with class singletons. Replace all the `main()` functions with entrypoint functions that could be dispatched from a single, unifying `main()` function. That sounds like a lot of work and a fair amount of disruption to all the other developers on the project. Is there truly no alternative on the compiler/linker level?

(I also don't want to just archive the binaries inside the CombinedProgram, write them to disk, and exec them. Boo. If I wanted a tarball, I'd just use a tarball.)

My understanding of C/C++ binary production is that the compiler will insert a `crt0` startup routine that will initialize all my global state and then invoke `main()` with the appropriate parameters. Could I... perhaps... sneak some code in *before* that `crt0` that peeks at argv and then proceeds down the correct code path?

Comment: I'm sure this is possible, I'm equally sure that it'll be horribly horribly hacky and fragile. I suppose you could do something less hacky like `#define main ProgramFooMain` with a different define for each executable, it'd definitely be simpler to implement it properly

Comment: Replace all but one of the `main`s with other function names.  Link the whole lot together. Parse the command line in the remaining `main` and call the one of the renamed `main`s depending on the command line passed.

Comment: Write another program which receives the name of the child program to run, then save all the other programs in subdirectories if their name are the same

Comment: @RichardCritten I thought about that, but wouldn't that cause the global state from all 66 binaries to be allocated at boot time of the combined binary?

Comment: Yes - if that's not what you want then @MarcoBeninca suggestion is better.

Comment: If you really want to go down the route of combining them and execing without writing to disk one option would be to use [`memfd_create`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) to create an anonymous in-memory file, then write out whatever program you want to execute to that in-memory file, Then you can use [`fexecve`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fexecve.3.html) to exec that program, using the fd returned from `memfd_create`. That way your executable will never have to be written out to disk.

Comment: @Turtlefight Ooh, that does seem promising. I'd presumably need to statically compile the shared library, but I can live with that...

Comment: @iameli here's a small example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3Mzqb1TME). if you need shared libraries you could most likely get away with loading them into a memfd as well and then adding them to the `LD_PRELOAD` env variable for the exec call (e.g. `LD_PRELOAD=/proc/self/fd/memfd:some_name`). That way the shared library will be preloaded into the exec'd process.

Comment: Another option would be to write your files to `/run/user/<user id>/<your program name>` - `/run` is usually backed by a tmpfs, so the result should be very similar to using `memfd_create`. (with the added benefit that you don't need to extract the binary again if it's already present in `/run`)

Answer (score 0):

### Is there truly no alternative on the compiler/linker level?

Not really. Refactoring is the best / least work way to accomplish your task.

% cc -o one busy.c ; ln one two ; ./one ; ./two
one
two

The `main()` needs to look at `ARGV[0]` to determine how it was called. Then act on that information.

Simplest example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int one(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("one\n");
    return 1;
}

int two(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("two\n");
    return 2;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *end = argv[0];
    int len = strlen(end);
    end += len; // jump to the end of the command.
    if (argc >= 1) {
        if (!strcmp(end-3, "one")) {
            return one(argc, argv);
        } else if (!strcmp(end-3, "two")) {
            return two(argc, argv);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know of a tool that automatically refactors the commands into functions. The alternative is having one file determine what to do and then exec one of the 66 other statically-linked binaries.